# Line of Sight/Clear Path Check Theta* For Rectangle Character

Tags: path-finding, tilemap

I am implementing Theta* pathfinding in a tile-based 2D game. A tile is either blocked or unblocked. The character has a rectangle collider with a width and height in tiles. Is there an algorithm for finding all the tiles the rectangle will overlap when moving in a straight line from A to B on the tile grid?

Comment: [One possible solution is presented here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/186621/39518). The final version there works with a circle, but the first step approximates the circle as a rectangle, so you can use that rectangular version to solve your problem